# How to show a Help or Notice to user in android application

Tags: android, alert, notice

i recently created a application so i want to give a descreption or help to the application .

Like a hint or alert  so that user can refer this and if he want this show every time or on first time
like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mtCUqhYAA_0/UB11q1OstYI/AAAAAAAAB1M/SfHn5OAPee8/s1600/TubeMate-1%5B2%5D.png)

so after installing the app should give this notice if user dont want that notice he can hide it for ever..
How to show this kind of alert.. i tried with alert but it always displays i want it just like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mtCUqhYAA_0/UB11q1OstYI/AAAAAAAAB1M/SfHn5OAPee8/s1600/TubeMate-1%5B2%5D.png)

[image]

Comment: It is simple custom dialog in android and you can use this as per your requirement.check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android/13342157#13342157)

Comment: This sis also fine chintan khetiya sir.. i am not checking your comment.. i am seeing answer, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to create simple custom alertdialog with the custom layout as show [HERE](http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-alertdialog-with-checkbox/)

Comment: Sorry grishma dixit mam.. Thanks a lot i am working with this but finally its worked, i am new to android so i used to copy paste but i need to change my way.. i got that code just i need little bit practice...

Comment: Thanks a Lot for And advance Happy new year.. may be you are elder or younger than me but i will respect every one with sir or medam.. so please ignore. that..Thank you

Comment: Happy New Year to you also. :)

Answer (score 0):

did you check this library, i found it really usefull :
https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Answer (score 0):

The second one is quiet easier then the previous one and its nothing but an `AlertDialog` and you may keep track of it by persisting its state via `shared-preferences` or `Sqlite Db`.

And for the previous case without googling for an opensource project I would recommend you to create your own `RelativeLayout` and place some `imageViews` at the respective positions and for persisting the states go by the above mentioned methodology.

Answer (score 0):

use one transparent layout and maintain your help text on it, using images to draw the layout.
check this link it gives some idea for that help layout.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950982/android-application-tutorialhelp-screen)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for my next app i will add this...